# Change file name in git repository, but not on file system?

Tags: git

I have a config file in my git repository, but I only want to commit a sample config file, with the same name as my real config. I.e, on my file system, I would have two files, `config.txt` and `_config.txt`. What I want is to keep `config.txt` and `_config.txt` separate on the file system, but commit `_config.txt` under the name of `config.txt`. Is this possible? If so, how can I do it?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Do you want something equivalent to stashing `config.txt`, then `cp _config.txt config.txt`, commit `config.txt` and then stash pop ?

Comment: I want to commit _config.txt, and have git think it's config.txt, but config.txt is separate on the filesystem.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a way to do what you're looking for.  However, if the `config.txt` in your git repository is just an example, then commit it with a name of something like `config-example.txt`, and tell git to ignore your local `config.txt`.

Comment: Right. I want to commit config-example.txt as if it was config.txt. Git would THINK it was config.txt, but in reality it was config-example.txt, while it ignored the real config.txt.

Comment: So if someone else checks out the repository, what should they see in `config.txt`?  And if they make changes to it and push, what would happen to your local clone once you pull?

Comment: They should see whatever was in _config.txt.

Answer (score 0):

The functionality you want is usually implemented this way:

- the sample config file is named `config.txt.dist` and is added to the repository; it contains default values (empty values for paths, connection parameters and other data that depends on the install/deployment location);
- the real config file is named `config.txt` and is added to `.gitignore` (the be ignored by `git`);
- the install or deployment script generates `config.txt` from `config.txt.dist` and (optionally) deletes `config.txt.dist`; it must not overwrite `config.txt` if it already exists;
- for bonus points, the code could use `config.txt.dist` if it is present and `config.txt` is missing; of course, this approach is appropriate if the config file contain only (the default) options and not paths, connection parameters and other installation-specific data.

Comment: Right, this is a method that would work for deployment, but I'm asking as a way of storing things in a repository. I take it there is no way to directly do what I want?

Comment: It works very well for development too. When the developers clone the repository, they make a copy of `config.txt.dist` as `config.txt`, maybe change some values in it and they are ready to go. Further customization (local paths, different database credentials a.s.o.) are done to `config.txt` without accidentally adding them to the repository. Also, each developer can have their own values in `config.txt` without affecting the other developers.